# Running SBT as Daemon

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an SBT scala application that runs fine using "sbt run". However, this locks up the console, and I'd rather start it as a service/daemon so that I can use the console, and also so that I can add it to init.d to ensure that my application is started automatically on startup.

I can't seem to find a way to do this. Running "sbt run &" seems to hang the app in the background.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We launch test/demo apps with SBT in init.d all the time:

```
#!/bin/sh
# test lift web app

case "$1" in
'start')
    cd /home/demouser/wa/HTML5DemoLift231/HTML5demo/
    sbt jetty run
    ;;
'stop')
    cd /home/demouser/wa/HTML5DemoLift231/HTML5demo/
    sbt jetty stop
    ;;
*)
    echo "Usage: $0 { start | stop }"
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

This just works - we have had no problems with it. It may be different with a non-web app though.

Comment: Thanks. Changing this to the correct answer. This eliminates the package step and allows me to deploy faster.

Comment: It does starts but quits immediately. In my case I'm using sbt container:start. Any ideas?

Comment: Same here. It starts but then quits immediately. Any ideas?

Comment: @JhonnyEverson @JacobusR `sbt container:start shell` works around this by starting a command line shell after the container. But what's the correct way to do this? (Not use `sbt` directly, I suppose.)

Comment: @wodow  That's really useful. You want to answer my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544032/how-to-keep-sbt-running-after-executing-a-command/32544892?noredirect=1#comment52946920_32544892

Answer (score 9):

You could also jar up your application into a "fat" jar using either [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) or [sbt-onejar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar).

This will make it an executable jar and easily runnable via `java -jar jarname.jar`.

Comment: I guess I was hoping this would be built into SBT so that I could skip the package step, but I'll look into these.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) for keeping it in background. Anyway I can't think a good reason to do that. Whouldn't it be better to package the application and run the generated binaries in the background?

Comment: A good reason would be have a remote development machine, where designers can just upload html files and don't have to restart the service. I don't know how to do that in a packaged app.

Comment: I didn't thought about that. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Just type sbt runProd 
And then press Ctrl+D
The process will be running as a daemon process.