# How to keep sbt running (as a daemon process) after executing a command

Tags: sbt, scalatra

I want to launch scalatra server from sbt. How do I do that? The following does launch scalatra:

```
sbt "container:start"
```

But it exits immediately:

```
[info] starting server ...
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Sep 12, 2015 2:39:32 PM
> [info] waiting for server to shut down...
```

Most preferably the whole thing would run in a nohup as a daemon process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sbt "; <command>; console"
```

does the trick. Note the initial semicolon *is* required.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it on one line. Use two commands.

```
./sbt
container:start
```

Comment: Hi avanti. Is your suggestion here addressing starting sbt as a daemon?

Comment: If you want to start your scalatra app as a daemon you should use Jetty or another web server. `sbt` is a build tool. It will open a new command process in the foreground and while it's there you can run commands such as `container:start` which launches your scalatra app and keeps it running. However, this is not an appropriate way to launch a scalatra app in anything other than a local development environment.

Comment: You said "I want to launch scalatra server from sbt [and keep it running]". That's how you do it. If you want more info on running a scalatra app outside of sbt, ask that question and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Thx Avanti. I updated the question. I had also already said "Most preferably the whole thing would run in a nohup as a daemon process."  If it were really true that sbt does not allow running as a daemon then i can award your question. i will look further into it.

Comment: Here's a way to daemonize the sbt process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000362/running-sbt-as-daemon?lq=1