# Preventing enter from stopping sbt run command

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.0, akka

In my play application, whenever I do sbt run, the server starts and a line gets printed

> Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console

Can I override this behaviour so that enter doesn't stops the server

Comment: Would running sbt as a daemon be a solution for you? Then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000362/running-sbt-as-daemon .